# How to enable virtualhost in xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am configure virtualhost on **Xampp** so that I can run an advanced **Yii2** project (with front and backend application), I have followed [this instruction](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md) and my `httpd-vhosts.conf` looks like this

```
    <VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName winnersprimary.ac.tz
    DocumentRoot 'c:\xampp\htdocs\winnersprimary\frontend\web\'
    <Directory 'c:\xampp\htdocs\winnersprimary\frontend\web\'>
            # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
            RewriteEngine on
            # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
            RewriteRule . index.php

            # use index.php as index file
            DirectoryIndex index.php

            # ...other settings...
            # Apache 2.4
            Require all granted
            
            ## Apache 2.2
            # Order allow,deny
            # Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

    <VirtualHost *:8081>
        ServerName admin.winnersprimary.ac.tz
        DocumentRoot 'c:\xampp\htdocs\winnersprimary\backend\web\'
        <Directory 'c:\xampp\htdocs\winnersprimary\backend\web\'>
                # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
                RewriteEngine on
                # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
                RewriteRule . index.php
    
                # use index.php as index file
                DirectoryIndex index.php
    
                # ...other settings...
                # Apache 2.4
                Require all granted
                
                ## Apache 2.2
                # Order allow,deny
                # Allow from all
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

while apache **main port is 8081** and **SSL port 4433** but it gives the error as shown on the picture bellow and the `error.log` says `[Sat Jun 19 11:01:06.453372 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 11044:tid 172] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name` how should I solve this error? I have tried several times to change the port numbers with no success.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it and I would like to share my solution here as it might help someone out there, I run `apache_start.bat` on **xammp** shell and found that was writing `DocumentRoot` in this way `DocumentRoot "c:\xampp\htdocs\winnersprimary\frontend\web\"` instead of this way `DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/winnersprimary/frontend/web/"` note the difference on the slashes :) [Click here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=70548) for reference

Answer (score 0):

On XAMPP Control Panel click on Explorer which is below Shell
(This will  open xampp file explorer)

Select and open apache folder and go to conf/extra folder
Inside the xampp/apache/conf/extra folder, the file you’re looking for is called httpd-ssl.conf
This file deals with the SSL configuration for your XAMPP Apache installation.

Open httpd-ssl file in any editor and search for ServerName [www.example.com:443](http://www.example.com:443)

Comment out this line by just adding # infront of it.

Next, you can add the text “ServerName winnersprimary.ac.tz” on the line directly below it.

Save and close file

Restart Apache or Xampp Control panel

Comment: Thank you so much for the idea, I have tried it and still gives the same error